# Jquery convert hmm format to hour

Tags: jquery, time

My weather forecast program use a service. This service give me time for each day. But this time format is 'hmm'. I don't know this format. So ı ask how can ı convert this ??

```
    $('.table tbody tr:eq(' + j + ') td:eq(0)').text(data.weather[gunSayisi].hourly[j].time);
```

this is my code ı got json data ı want to convert this time format to hour
Here is my data : http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=0e98f3e93aeb98d337bb8b0df25928ed

Comment: share your code...

Comment: divide by 100, ignore remainder.  It's clearly h mm, where h will be 1-12 (no leading 0) rather than hh which would be 00-23

Comment: Hello guys this is my data you can see time format http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=0e98f3e93aeb98d337bb8b0df25928ed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hmm` means hour minute minute, so, to reach the number of `hours` as an integer, you need to divide and round, like this:

```
var hours = Math.floor(value / 100);
```

If you want to get the number as float, then you need to gather the number of `hours`, the number of minutes and convert the number of minutes into decimals:

```
var h = parseInt(value.substring(0, value.length - 2));
var m = parseInt(value.substring(value.length - 2));
var hours = h + (m / 60);
```

Or in short:

```
var hours = parseInt(value.substring(0, value.length - 2)) + (parseInt(value.substring(value.length - 2)) / 60);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var time = parseInt(time)
var hour = Math.floor(time/100);
var minute = time % 100;
```

This should work.